# ServletContextとFaceContextの使いどころを教えてほしい

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

実行環境

java 1.8
eclipse
payara server

ServletContextを@injectしてmethodのgetRealpathを使おうとすると
nullpointerexceptionがでてServletContextの変数の中はnullですよというエラーが出ます
仕様を調べてみると
getRealPath
public java.lang.String getRealPath（java.lang.String path）
このメソッドは、サーブレットコンテナが何らかの理由（コンテンツがアーカイブwar から利用可能になっている場合など）で仮想パスを実際のパスに変換できない場合にnull返されます。

おそらくこれが原因のようです

```
    @SessionScoped
    public class FileReader implements Serializable{
    @Context
    private ServletContext context;
    public String readAllText(String fpath) {
    String path = context.getRealPath(fpath);
    
    Path p = Paths.get(path);
    String data = "";
    try {
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(p);
        data = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return data;
```

また上記の仕様書からするとこのプログラムは読み込ませれないのでしょうか？

Comment: 何かやりたいことがあってその実装方法を知りたいのか、質問文中のコードが(想定通り)動作するかどうかが知りたいのか(動かないことは検証済みだと思うので、これは即ちなぜ例外が出るのかが知りたいのかということになろうかと思います)、 `ServletContext`と`FaceContext` の使いどころ(具体的な利用例)が知りたいのか、質問のタイトルや本文を読む限り不明瞭に感じました。もう少し焦点を絞って質問する方が回答が付きやすいように思われます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ServletContextとFaceContext の使いどころ(具体的な利用例)とこのコードがnullpointerexceptionにならない方法が知りたいです。

Comment: このコードはどういう動作を期待したものでしょうか(最終的にやりたいことは何でしょうか)。

Comment: fpathがnullにならないことを期待しています。

Comment: `fpath` は `readAllText` メソッドの引数であり、 `null` であるかどうかは呼び出し元次第です。ですので、それを回答するには、どう呼び出しているかの情報が必要です。

Comment: 多分それにこたえてもよくわからないと思います

Comment: 話はシンプルです。なぜservletcontextがnullになってしまうのかどうか説明できますか？

Comment: そしてそれがそういう仕様であるからという回答の場合ではどういうときに使うのか説明できますか？

Comment: ちなみにログStandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at bean.FileReader.readAllText(FileReader.java:18)
 at bean.FileReader$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.readAllText(Unknown Source)
 at bean.Bb.next(Bb.java:21)